# Removing a DOM element in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to remove a particular block of HTML tags from DOM onclick.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
  <th width="90%">{{ item.file.name}}({{item.file.size/1000000}} MB)</th>
  <th class="text-center" width="10%">
    <mat-icon (click)="item.remove()">delete</mat-icon>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Here .remove() is working properly.

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of uploaded_files">
  <th width="90%">{{uploaded_files}} </th>
  <th class="text-center" width="10%">
    <mat-icon (click)="items.remove()">delete</mat-icon>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Here .remove() is not working properly.
Which shows an error as follows :
_v.context.$implicit.remove is not a function(…)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remove item from array and just want to remove element then

You have to add `#item` into tr tag and then you have to change `items.remove()` to `item.remove()`

Ex:

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of uploaded_files" #item>
    <th width="90%">{{uploaded_files}} </th>
    <th class="text-center" width="10%">
        <mat-icon (click)="item.remove()">delete</mat-icon>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `uploaded_files` is an array, and as such does not necessarily have a delete function on its elements.

You could, however, remove elements by index eg

```
public removeUploadedFile(index: number): void {
   uploaded_files.splice(index, 1);
}
```

and

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of uploaded_files; let i = index">
  <th width="90%">{{uploaded_files}} </th>
  <th class="text-center" width="10%">
    <mat-icon (click)="removeUploadedFile(i)">delete</mat-icon>
  </th>
</tr>
```